# How to avoid accidentally closing an SQL Connection in Java?

Tags: java, sql, connection, database-connection, sqlcommand

Currently what i am doing for transaction management is:

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
updateTableX ( connection, ... );
updateTableY ( connection, ... );
connection.commit();
closeConnection();
```

I would like to know, if it is possible to avoid closing the connection in my 'updateTableX' method. Because if someone accidentally closes the connection then my updateTableY will not be having the connection and it will throw the exception.

Comment: What do you mean with "if someone accidentally closes the connection"?

Comment: i mean in updateTableX, if someone write connection.close(); , then he should be allowed to do that.

Comment: The question is poorly phrased.  It's not clear exactly what you mean - programmatically make close a no-op, or simply use a pattern that doesn't promote the behaivor of closing anywhere.

Comment: I would question that @Rakesh. if the connection is passed in as a param and is open the function should do nothing more than use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just discipline. In general, methods shouldn't try to take responsibility for closing things passed into them as parameters - with the exception of situations where you create a new object to wrap an existing one.

The way to avoid closing the connection in `updateTableX` is just to make sure you don't put a call to `close()` into the code. This is no different than any other bug really. How do you stop `updateTableX` from arbitrarily updating a different table, or throwing an exception, or doing anything else it's not meant to? Code reviews, unit tests, integration tests, manual testing etc...

I mean you *could* write a `Connection` implementation which wraps another connection and proxies all the methods through *except* `close()` but it sounds like a waste of time - if you don't trust the developers involved not to close the connection, do you trust them to get the rest of the code right?

Comment: i like the way you replied :D . +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

Like Jon said, if you really want to forbit to call `close()` you could write a decorator implementation that forwards to your "real" `Connection` object. I don't post a code example because the `Connection` interface is too big. With modern IDEs however it is no problem to generate the code.

Recipe (presuming you're using Eclipse):

1. Create a class that implements `Connection`, but do not implement the methods
2. Create a field `private Connection delegate;`
3. Select the field name -> Source (Menu) -> "Generate Constructor using fields" -> make sure the field is selected and press ok
4. Select the field name -> Source (Menu) -> "Generate Delegate Methods..." -> check every method on you field
5. Change the implementation of the `close()` method to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`

However like Jon said, I would really think about doing something like that. And maybe you just use a Object-Relational-Mapper (e.g. [Hiberate](http://www.hibernate.org)) to encapsulate all of your Database access logic. An additional very helpful framework in this area is [Spring](http://www.springframework.org), especially if you do not want to care about `Connection` and `DataSource` handling.

Answer (score 0):

*(I am unfamiliar with Java specifically)*

Assuming you have some sort of database managing object, you could have it make sure it is connected before it attempts any operations.

You could try to restrict access to closing the connection but how would you decide if it should be closed, or if it's "accidental" (however you define that)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible.

You can technically make a copy of your connection object, but then what happens if the client programmer *doesn't* close the connection?